# Magento resize different size images to unique size. Read description.

Tags: product, product-attribute, product-list, product-images, image-upload

I am having a catalog with different sized images. Some will be 200x300 some will be 300x150. But All i want to do is to resize all the image to one size which makes me to show in my home page listing.

I am trying the normal magento resize to crop tp **160x210** as follows,

```
   <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(false)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)->resize(160, 210); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" />
```

But its cropping images in different size, The images are in random height and widths **160x135, 160x156, 159x210, 150x210**

Detailed answers are highly appreciated.

Comment: did you get a proper answer?

Answer (score 9):

Either set keepFrame to true, so it's always exact 160x210, or set keepAspectRatio to false.

Now it is making sure both width and height won't exceed the values you feed it. But since you don't want a frame, and want to keep your aspect ratio, it has to change both width and height in the same ratio.

```
<?php 
echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')
    ->constrainOnly(false)
    ->keepAspectRatio(true)
    ->keepFrame(true)
    ->resize(160, 210);
?>
```

Edit:
For cropping you need to use `Varien_Image`. Unfortunately the `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image` doesn't offer a method to return the `Varien_Image` class. So you need to make a custom module to make it possible to crop.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492770/magento-crop-image for an example.

Basically it says you need to make your own helper and extend Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image, so you can use `$this->_getModel()->getImageProcessor()->crop()`

Comment: Yeah. If I follow that method, The images are stretching. Do we have anyother methods not to make images stretch??
I dont want frames at all..

Comment: I don't understand, there are 3 methods now, build a frame around the image to make it exactly your requested size, stretch the image to your requested size or just stick to the max height / width and change the other value with the same ratio. I don't see which other method you want?

Comment: There is a one more method... The method etsy.com is following, they are cropping the image from the center and resize it to the exact size. Do magento have any functions like that. ?

Comment: Ah you mean like that, didn't think of that. Well, it is possible but a bit more complicated. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492770/magento-crop-image for an example.

Comment: Do you think this one is working??? Did you try that before?

Comment: See my edited answer. I didn't try it before, but I'm pretty sure it will work. The `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image` has a method _getModel(), which returns an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image`, which has a method `getImageProcessor()`, which returns an instance of `Varien_Image`. And that class finally has the crop method. It's a bit nasty, but unfortunatelly the image helper is a bit messed up.

Comment: Yes. Let me get back to you soon after trying.. I will upvote if it works. otherwise, I will inform you.

Comment: Be aware that this will NOT WORK WITH FLAT CATALOG enabled

Answer (score 0):

For resizing image, use the below code :
//  image size will be 200x200

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame(false)->resize(200); ?>" />
```

// image size 200x220;

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame(false)->resize(200, 220); ?>" />
```

// sometimes the image size alters after using resize() function and it shows a white space at both the sides on left and right, so you can also adjust the width and height using this code:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame(false)->resize(); ?>"  width="200" height="220"/>
```